# how to understand the concept of Object Container Files in avro?

Tags: avro

I'm quite confused about the concept of *Object Container Files* in Avro.

> https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Object+Container+Files

Does Object Container Files mean the files which produced by Avro when serializing the data? Avro persist the serialized data into one or more files, does this file call *Object Container Files*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're to store Avro files on disk, those are represented by the Container file specifications mentioned there.

The files contain binary data, after data is serialized

One file contains a schema and many serialized records matching that schema